# LINQ: Order By Anonymous Type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, sql-order-by

Hello I am using linq to fill a gridview with the information from an xml from codebehind. I would like to order my Grid according to one of my elements in the xml ("value element") but can't figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

```
    gvResourceEditor.DataSource = (From resElem In resourceElements.Elements("data") _
    Select New With { _
   .Key = resElem.Attribute("name").Value, _
   .Value = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(resElem.Element("value").Value), _
   .Comment = If(resElem.Element("comment") IsNot Nothing, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(resElem.Element("comment").Value), String.Empty) _
      }).OrderBy(?????)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gvResourceEditor.DataSource = _
   From resElem In resourceElements.Elements("data") _
     Select Data = New With { _
       .Key = resElem.Attribute("name").Value, _
       .Value = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(resElem.Element("value").Value), _
       .Comment = If(resElem.Element("comment") IsNot Nothing, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(resElem.Element("comment").Value), String.Empty) _
     } Order By Data.Value
```