# Order by fields in an anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0, linq-to-objects

I am using LINQ to Objects to aggregate:

```
  var summary = from esc in objs
                where esc.time.Month == month && esc.time.Year == year
                group esc by esc.rlf_id into g
                select new { 
                  ID = g.Key, 
                  Total = g.Count(), 
                  Preventable = g.Where(a => a.preventable).Count() 
                };
```

My query works as I would expect, but I also want to order the query by arbitrary field(s) in the anonymous type. I found [LINQ: Order By Anonymous Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742509/linq-order-by-anonymous-type), but it's in VB.NET and requires strongly specifying what field to sort by. I can conceptualize what I want to accompilish with this pseudocode:

```
query = get all esc in obj
        aggregate into anonymous type with key ID
          ID = g.Key, Total = g.Count, Preventable = g.Count of preventable
        orderby inputField[0], (optional thenby inputField[1], ..., thenby inputField[n])
```

How do I accomplish:

- <del>*Sorting by an anonymous type's field in a LINQ query*</del> **(done - thank you Marko!)**
- Further sorting by arbitrary field(s) of the anonymous type

I am open to dot syntax or query syntax.

Edit: 
With Marko Stanojevic's answer, I am able to partially meet my requirements. I was unaware that I am able to chain LINQ methods together like that. I now am able to (and get expected results from):

```
var summary = from esc in objs
              where esc.time.Month == month && esc.time.Year == year
              group esc by esc.rlf_id into g
              select new { 
                ID = g.Key, 
                Total = g.Count(), 
                Preventable = g.Where(a => a.preventable).Count() 
              };
summary = summary.OrderBy(e => e.Total);
```

What I need is something that lets me do: (pseudocode)

```
summary = summary.<Order/Then>By<(optional)Descending>(e => e.<someUserInput>)
```

Given some string that specifies how the user wants to sort, obviously I can do:

```
if (sortQuery.Equals("Total", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoresCase), bool descending) {
  summary = descending ? summary.OrderByDescending(e => e.Total) : summary.OrderBy(e => e.total)
} else if (sortQuery.Equals( /* ... etc */
```

However, this ends up being ugly quick-like, especially because I would like to use this for a (potentially nearly infinite) growing number of queries. It would also need to account for `OrderBy()` versus `ThenBy()`.

I wish I was working with C# 4 so I could use dynamic right about now...

Comment: `if(..) query = query.OrderBy(..); if(..) query = query.ThenBy(..);`

Comment: You can always perform an `orderby` just before the `group` if it is of any help.

Comment: I agree with George. Order the summary prior to doing the group, then apply your select.

Comment: @kryptonkal Elaborate? Sure I can order by the key (because that's available then) but the Total and Preventable fields are not;

Comment: My apologies, I had missed that. I had only read order by ID.

Comment: @jdphenix If my reply is not sufficient, thank you to add a comment explaining what is missing

Comment: @nlips It's actually pretty close to perfect, in a few (days?) I'm going to update it with my eventual usage for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the data type is anonymous is not important and does not change the problem. An anonymous type is a type as another (it just has a special name). Like other types it is completely known at compile time! You can read [Anonymous Type vs Dynamic Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391529/anonymous-type-vs-dynamic-type) to learn more about difference between anonymous and dynamic types.

The difficulty is that the methods (eg `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`) to invoke and their parameters (eg the keySelector `item => item.MyFieldName`) are known only at runtime.

**The solution is to use Reflection**.

The code below implements the `OrderByRules` function as an extension method that applies to any collection of type `IQueryable<T>` (So, to any collection of type `IEnumerable<T>` using simply the `AsQueryable<T>()` operator.

The first rule is processed in a special way to use the `OrderBy` operator and not `ThenBy`. Then the others are processed recursively.

The call to sort operator is performed in the function `OrderByFieldOrPropertyName`. From the field or property reflection information, we construct a lambda expression of the form `item => item.fieldName`. The MakeGenericMethod function is used to construct the concrete method. Basically, it allows you to switch from `OrderBy<T>` to `OrderBy<MyData>`.

I hope that answers your question.

```
/// <summary>
/// Express an order rule based on property name
/// </summary>
public class OrderRule
{
    public OrderRule(string fieldOrPropertyName, bool descending)
    {
        FieldOrPropertyName = fieldOrPropertyName;
        Descending = descending;
    }
    public string FieldOrPropertyName { get; private set; }
    public bool Descending { get; private set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Static class holding the OrderByRules extension method
/// </summary>
static public class MyLINQExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Order <paramref name="dataCollection"/> according to <paramref name="rules"/> sequence
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Collection item type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="dataCollection">Queryable collection</param>
    /// <param name="rules">Order rules to apply</param>
    /// <returns>Ordered queryable collection</returns>
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByRules<T>(this IQueryable<T> dataCollection, IEnumerable<OrderRule> rules)
    {
        if (!rules.Any())
            throw new ArgumentException("Rules list is empty", "rules");
        // apply first rule (special case: use OrderBy operator and not ThenBy)
        OrderRule rule = rules.First();
        MethodInfo orderOperator = rule.Descending ? OrderByDescendingMethodInfo : OrderByMethodInfo;
        IOrderedQueryable<T> orderedDataCollection = OrderByFieldOrPropertyName(dataCollection, orderOperator, rule.FieldOrPropertyName);
        // apply next rules recursivly
        return OrderByRulesRecursivly(orderedDataCollection, rules.Skip(1).ToList());
    }

    static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByFieldOrPropertyName<T>(IQueryable<T> dataCollection, MethodInfo orderOperator, string fieldOrPropertyName)
    {
        // member corresponding to fieldOrPropertyName
        MemberInfo memberInfo = typeof(T).GetField(fieldOrPropertyName);
        Type memberType = null;
        if (memberInfo == null)
            memberInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(fieldOrPropertyName);
        else
            memberType = (memberInfo as FieldInfo).FieldType;
        if (memberInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Field or property '{0}' doesn't exist on type '{1}'", fieldOrPropertyName, typeof(T)));
        else
            memberType = (memberInfo as PropertyInfo).PropertyType;
        // build lambda expression: item => item.fieldName
        ParameterExpression paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        LambdaExpression keySelectorExp = Expression.Lambda(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(paramExp, memberInfo), paramExp);
        // build concrete MethodInfo from the generic one
        orderOperator = orderOperator.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), memberType);
        // invoke method on dataCollection
        return orderOperator.Invoke(null, new object[] {
            dataCollection,
            keySelectorExp
        }) as IOrderedQueryable<T>;
    }

    static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByRulesRecursivly<T>(IOrderedQueryable<T> dataCollection, List<OrderRule> rules)
    {
        if (!rules.Any())
            return dataCollection;
        // apply first rule
        OrderRule rule = rules.First();
        MethodInfo orderOperator = rule.Descending ? ThenByDescendingMethodInfo : ThenByMethodInfo;
        IOrderedQueryable<T> orderedDataCollection = OrderByFieldOrPropertyName(dataCollection, orderOperator, rule.FieldOrPropertyName);
        // apply next rules recursivly
        return OrderByRulesRecursivly(orderedDataCollection, rules.Skip(1).ToList());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Static constructor. Initialize Reflection informations about Order operators
    /// </summary>
    static MyLINQExtensions()
    {
        // public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector);
        OrderByMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2);
        // public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByDescending<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector);
        OrderByDescendingMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(m => m.Name == "OrderByDescending" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2);
        // public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> ThenBy<TSource, TKey>(this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector);
        ThenByMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(m => m.Name == "ThenBy" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2);
        // public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> ThenByDescending<TSource, TKey>(this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector);
        ThenByDescendingMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(m => m.Name == "ThenByDescending" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2);
    }

    static MethodInfo OrderByMethodInfo;
    static MethodInfo OrderByDescendingMethodInfo;
    static MethodInfo ThenByMethodInfo;
    static MethodInfo ThenByDescendingMethodInfo;
}
```

To be compiled, the code requires that the following namespaces are declared in the header:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
```

Now you can use `OrderByRules` on your context:

```
var summaryOrdered = summary.OrderByRules(new List<OrderRule> {
    new OrderRule("Total", true),
    new OrderRule("Preventable", false)
});
```

This will order the collection by *Total* (descending) and then by *Preventable* (ascending).

Comment: This is nuts.  Why not just use the `.OrderBy` / `.OrderByDescending` extension methods? -- They work fine with anonymous types.

Comment: @BrainSlug83, problem concerns not so much anonymous types BUT order rule known only at runtime. @jdphenix pseudo-code : `summary = summary.<Order/Then>By<(optional)Descending>(e => e.<someUserInput>)`

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what's the problem. After you calculate summary, you can simply

```
summary = summary.OrderBy(s => s.Total).ToList();
```

Properties of the anonymous type are visible right away. If you want to pass it around and have problems, than the easiest solution is to create a class, since you know what it looks like. If you don't want to create custom class for some reason, I guess you can use `Tuple` for example:

```
var summary = from esc in objs
                where esc.time.Month == month && esc.time.Year == year
                group esc by esc.rlf_id into g
                select new Tuple<long, int, int> ( 
                  g.Key, 
                  g.Count(), 
                  g.Where(a => a.preventable).Count() 
                );
```

Then you can sort by `.Item1` or `.Item2` etc. Still, I would use custom class since it is more clear what is going on.

Comment: I am considering a model class for just the clarity reason, thanks for the post

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/1486443).

Try this:

```
// Optional properties for dynamic sorting
var orders = new[]
{
    new OrderByPropertyName {Desc = true, PropertyName = "Preventable"},
    new OrderByPropertyName {Desc = false, PropertyName = "ID"},
    new OrderByPropertyName {Desc = true, PropertyName = "Total"},
};

var firstOrder = orders.First();

var sortedSummary = firstOrder.Desc
    ? summary.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(firstOrder.PropertyName)
    : summary.AsQueryable().OrderBy(firstOrder.PropertyName);

foreach (var order in orders.Except(new[] {firstOrder}))
{
    sortedSummary = order.Desc
        ? summary.OrderByDescending(order.PropertyName)
        : summary.OrderBy(order.PropertyName);
}

var result = sortedSummary.ToList();
```